# Not getting expected output while using log4j

Tags: java, log4j

I made a simple class and tried to print the log messages using Logger class methods and used FileAppender to append the log messages to the file.
But the logs are not printed in file.

> Can anyone guide me how should I print these logs in a file using the program  I made.
>   I used a log4j-1.2.17 Api in the classpath:

Code for the below program:

```
public class Client {
static Logger l=Logger.getLogger(Client.class.getName());
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Layout l1=new SimpleLayout();
    Appender a;
    try{
        a=new FileAppender(l1,"my.txt",true);
        l.debug("Hello Jc");
        l.info("Hello Jc");
        l.fatal("This is not the error message");
        l.addAppender(a);
    }
    catch(Exception e){
    }
    System.out.println("your logic executed Successfully");
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}
```

Output:

```
log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger (Client).
log4j:WARN Please initialize the log4j system properly.
log4j:WARN See http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/faq.html#noconfig for more info.
your logic executed Successfully
```

Expected Output in file:

```
DEBUG Hello Jc

INFO Hello Jc

FATAL This is not the error message
```

Comment: do you have log4j.properties or log4j.xml in your classpath with appender for your class and package?

Comment: No I haven't used .properties or xml but I used a simple java class to have appender and layout object.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger (Client). log4j:WARN
>   Please initialize the log4j system properly. log4j:WARN

```
    a = new FileAppender(l1,"my.txt",true);
    l.debug("Hello Jc");
    l.info("Hello Jc");
    l.fatal("This is not the error message");
    l.addAppender(a); // too late
```

You have this problem because you try to log before that the file appender be added to the configuration. How to log without any appender ?

So move up `l.addAppender(a)` before logging operations :

```
a = new FileAppender(l1,"my.txt",true);
l.addAppender(a); // appender is added, you can log
l.debug("Hello Jc");
l.info("Hello Jc");
l.fatal("This is not the error message");
```

Answer (score 1):

Simply i have created some Util class to initialize log configuration;

```
public static void initLogger() {
    try {
      String filePath = "D:/my.log";
      PatternLayout layout = new PatternLayout("%-5p %d %m%n");
      RollingFileAppender appender = new RollingFileAppender(layout, filePath);
      appender.setName("log");
      appender.setMaxFileSize("10MB");
      appender.activateOptions();
      Logger.getRootLogger().addAppender(appender);
    } catch (IOException e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Then i call this method and successfully wrote to file;

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    LoggerUtil.initLogger();

    Logger accessLog = Logger.getLogger("log");

    accessLog.info("This is info message.");
    accessLog.warn("This is warn message.");
    accessLog.error("This is error message.");
    accessLog.fatal("This is fatal message.");
}
```